# Dell M4800 expand disk 0(ssd) with disk1(ssd mSata)

Tags: ssd, msata

I have Dell M4800 with ssd(256Gb). The space is full now. I bought one more ssd(256Gb) and install it to my laptop using mSata. Now i have two disks(full and empty) and i want to expand my disk c: with new space of new disk. Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it's not. You can create additional partitions in the new drive.

Comment: You can make a Backup of your data and create a JBOD. But I am note sure if your BIOS can so this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expand one disk over another.

The most you can do is to make the second disk appear as a folder in your first
disk, although I don't really see the advantage of using it via a folder than
via a drive-letter.

If this interests you, see the Microsoft article
[Assign a mount point folder path to a drive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/assign-a-mount-point-folder-path-to-a-drive):

> - In Disk Manager, right-click the partition or volume where you want to assign the mount point folder path.
> - Click *Change Drive Letter and Paths* and then click *Add*.
> - Click *Mount in the following empty NTFS folder*.
> - Type the path to an empty folder on an NTFS volume, or click *Browse* to locate it.

Comment: The linked instructions need to be at least summarized in your answer in case the link breaks.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: Will do if the poster does not reject the approach.

Comment: hmmm....It should not be based on that. Your answer if for everyone, not just this one poster.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: You win, I always lose these arguments...

Comment: your answer is much better with the included info. Thank you.